# is it possible to detect pointer-to-member-function?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

i want a specialize template in a pointer-to-member-function case. Is there a way to detect this? right now i declare struct isPtrToMemberFunc, then add an extra template (class TType=void) to each class (right now just 1) and specialize the extra template to see if its isPtrToMemberFunc. Is there a way to detect this automatically? if not is my current method the best solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way, but it includes that you repeat your specialization for each and every number of arguments and const/volatile modifiers for those member functions. An easier way to do that is to use `boost.functiontypes` which does that for you:

```
template<typename T>
void doit(T t) {
    if(boost::function_types::is_member_function_pointer<T>::value) {
        std::cout << "it is";
        // ...
    } else {
        std::cout << "it is not";
        // ...
    }
}
```

Grab it from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/index.html).